# Allowed memory size of x exhausted error on installing PHPUnit with Yii

Tags: php, phpunit, pear, yii

I'm following along with the book "Agile Web Application Development with Yii 1.1 and PHP5" and I just started the part about unit testing in chapter 2.

When I follow the instructions on installing PHPUnit through PEAR, I receive a fatal error `"Allowed memory size of x exhausted."` I tried increasing the allotted memory to 1024 in the top of PEAR.PHP using `ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');` But this just caused CLI to crash.

Here's the full error message:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\yii_sc2>pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
269279590 bytes) in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PEAR.php on line 719

Call Stack:
0.0015 535368 1. {main}() C:\xampp\php\PEAR\pearcmd.php:0
0.0986 3506816 2. PEAR::popErrorHandling() C:\xampp\php\PEAR\pearcmd.php:269
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What could it possibly be doing that's allocating over *256 megs*...

Comment: Before you install phpunit, make sure you have the latest pear installer, e.g. do `pear upgrade-all` until it tells you there is nothing left to upgrade.

Comment: This did not solve the problem, in fact when I try doing pear upgrade-all, php CLI stops working.

Comment: Can you save `http://pear.php.net/go-pear` to `C:\xampp\php\go-pear.php`, then run `php go-pear.php` and then try again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't change the memory limit in the PEAR.php file. It will likely get overwritten once you update PEAR. If changing the memory limit in the **php.ini for you php-cli executable** does not make the error go away, try to run

```
peardev upgrade-all
```

which is the same command as `pear` but has no memory limit. To install PHPUnit you have to have at least PEAR installer 1.9.1. You can verify your PEAR version by typing

```
pear version
```

Once everything is upgraded to the required version, run

```
peardev channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
peardev channel-discover components.ez.no
peardev channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
peardev install --alldeps --force phpunit/PHPUnit
```

If that still results in errors, consider dropping by at the official support channels

- [#pear at EFNet IRC](http://chat.efnet.org:9090/?channels=#pear&Login=Login)
- [#phpunit at Freenet IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net/)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up taking this route.  Turns out XAMPP comes with an outdated version of PEAR.

Comment: `peardev` is an unbelievable obscure thing for a solution.. but it sure worked where `pear install doc.php.net/pman` crashed w/ exhausted memory error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase your `memory_limit` parameter in your `php.ini` file.

Your current value is:
memory_limit = 16M

Change it to:
memory_limit = 64M

(or more, if you need)